# performance of calling one action from another action in same controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Is calling one action from another action in a same controller like calling one method from another method in class or have performance issues ?

```
public class MemberInformationController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult PersonalInfo()
    {
        return View("VPersonalInfo");
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditPersonalInfo(VMPersonalInfo InModel)
    {
        if (_member.ID_Member == 0) return Redirect(Url.Action("Login", "MemberShip"));

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            Member member = new Member();
            member.Address = InModel.Address;
            member.Email = InModel.Email;
            member.ID_Member = _member.ID_Member;
            member.MobilePhone = _member.MobilePhone;
            member.PhoneNumber = _member.PhoneNumber;
            member.UrgentPhoneNumber = _member.UrgentPhoneNumber;

            _blMemberShip.EditMember(member, ref Message);

            ViewBag.Message = "Successfully done";
            return this.PersonalInfo();
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Error in Operation";
            return this.PersonalInfo();
        }

    }
  }
```

For example in MemberInformationController PersonalInfo it is better to call PersonalInfo action from EditPersonalInfo or return View("VPersonalInfo") from EditPersonalInfo?

Answer (score 0):

It will not make any difference whether you return **VpersonalINfo** View from the action or call the above action to return the view.

You have both option, its up to you and depends on the business flow of the application, but it will not make any difference performance wise.